# Upload file to Nginx with cURL

Tags: nginx, curl

All,

I'm trying to upload a local file to my remote Nginx server via cURL. I have built Nginx from source with the [upload](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/) module and the DAV module. At the bottom of the Nginx page, there is an example form to upload a file. I'm not sure how I would implement the form, and (several) Google searches have returned little helpful information about uploading directly to Nginx via cURL.

Current tech stack:

- Nginx
- Green Unicorn
- Flask

Of all the different avenues I've tried, the following is the one that seems the most appropriate for the task.

```
curl -X POST -F "image=@example.gif" http://54.226.64.199/upload
```

However, the [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiDqt.png) is underwhelming.

I've tried --uploade-file as well, the response is a 405. From what I've read, upload only accepts a POST command, not PUT, hence why I get a 405.

I don't need a full solution (would be great!), only pointing in the right direction.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: sorry wanted to include part of my .conf

```
        location /upload {
        upload_store /tmp;
        #upload_pass @none;
        upload_store_access all:rw;
        upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;

    }
```

Comment: .. also print the nginx error logs

Comment: Hey, long story short, I was doing this the wrong way. Instead of trying to upload through Nginx, I uploaded through Flask. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: @Nashluffy: Can you please post your finding as an answer?

I am struggling with the same problem. Can't find cURL command to post to NGINX.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by specifying filename into URL, without using any external module :

```
location ~ "/upload/([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*)$" {
    alias     /storage/www/upload/$1;
    client_body_temp_path  /tmp/upload_tmp;
    dav_methods  PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
    create_full_put_path   on;
    dav_access             group:rw  all:r;
}
```

And use : curl -T example.gif http://54.226.64.199/upload/example.gif

Comment: You don't need all those `dav_methods`. For PUT, put _just_ PUT there.